# Is there an alternative to x2goclient?

Tags: alternative, x2go, x2goclient

I use lot of x2go sessions and I find the x2goclient in Ubuntu rather wasteful of screen space.

Is there an alternative more streamlined version of the x2goclient? I am not interested in an alternative to x2go itself, just an alternative to the client it is bundled with.

By alternative client I mean an alternative session launcher and manager

Answer (score 3):

**PyHoca-GUI** is exactly what you are looking for.

It is an alternative client developed by the X2GO Project. It is designed for for having numerous sessions open at once. (The regular X2Go Client is designed with thin clients in mind.)

Note: I am X2Go Developer :)

It is available on our PPAs: https://launchpad.net/~x2go

[http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:usage:pyhoca-gui](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc%3ausage%3apyhoca-gui)

Comment: Just tried doing an apt-get phyoca-gui on ubuntu 16.04. Running it failed miserably with a complaint about "NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3' is not defined"

Comment: Well same here, window with ugly icon appears for few second, then vanishes and that it.  Gives this message on command line:pyhoca-gui[22217] (PyHoca-GUI) WARN: the current release of PyHoca-GUI does not support client configuration

Comment: It seems to do nothing at first. But then I noticed a little icon in the tool tray with a menu that does everything you might need, and more than the x2goclient.

Answer (score 0):

Per Wikipedia:

X2Go is **not** compatible with other NX servers and clients.

[emphasis mine]

Comment: From what I see about x2goclient it is a wrapper for a command line client, which stores the connection settings and logs some output from the local XWindows client, like XMing (Windows). What I am interested in is another launcher but more streamlined